# Calculation using shifting is not working in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The problem consist on calculate from a dataframe the column "accumulated" using the columns "accumulated" and "weekly". The formula to do this is **accumulated in t = weekly in t + accumulated in t-1**

The desired result should be:

```
weekly  accumulated
   2          0
   1          1
   4          5
   2          7
```

The result I'm obtaining is:

```
weekly  accumulated
   2          0
   1          1
   4          4
   2          2
```

What I have tried is:

```
 for key, value in df_dic.items():
         df_aux = df_dic[key]
         df_aux['accumulated'] = 0  
         df_aux['accumulated'] = (df_aux.weekly + df_aux.accumulated.shift(1))
         #df_aux["accumulated"] = df_aux.iloc[:,2] + df_aux.iloc[:,3].shift(1) 
         df_aux.iloc[0,3] = 0 #I put this because I want to force the first cell to be 0.
```

Being df_aux.iloc[0,3] the first row of the column "accumulated".

What I´m doing wrong?

Thank you

EDIT: df_dic is a dictionary with 5 dataframes. df_dic is seen as {0: df1, 1:df2, 2:df3}. All the dataframes have the same size and same columns names. So i do the for loop to do the same calculation in every dataframe inside the dictionary.

EDIT2 : I'm trying doing the computation outside the for loop and is not working.
What im doing is:

```
df_auxp = df_dic[0]
df_auxp['accumulated'] = 0
df_auxp['accumulated'] = df_auxp["weekly"] + df_auxp["accumulated"].shift(1)
df_auxp.iloc[0,3] = df_auxp.iloc[0,3].fillna(0)
```

Maybe have something to do with the dictionary interaction...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is always useful to have your dataframes defined in code so others can test their proposed solutions easily, pls see [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Also in the snippet of code that you helpfully provided, `df_dic` is not defined so it cannot be run by others.

Comment: This is a single line solution. You dont need a for loop. Use `df['accumulated'] = df['weekly'].cumsum() - df.iloc[0,0]`

Comment: I need the for loop since I have to do the same calculation in 3 dataframes :/

Comment: You can iterate thru the 3 dataframes using a for loop. `for d in [df1, df2, df3]: d['accumulate'] = d['weekly'].cumsum() - d.iloc[0,0]`. This will iterate thru the 3 dataframes and do the calculations. Am I missing something?

Comment: See if the updated answer helps you with the 3 dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To solve for 3 dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'weekly':[2,1,4,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'weekly':[3,2,5,3]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'weekly':[4,3,6,4]})

print (df1)
print (df2)
print (df3)

for d in [df1,df2,df3]:
    d['accumulated'] = d['weekly'].cumsum() - d.iloc[0,0]
    print (d)
```

The output of this will be as follows:

**Original dataframes:**

df1

```
   weekly
0       2
1       1
2       4
3       2
```

df2

```
   weekly
0       3
1       2
2       5
3       3
```

df3

```
   weekly
0       4
1       3
2       6
3       4
```

**Updated dataframes:**

df1:

```
   weekly  accumulated
0       2            0
1       1            1
2       4            5
3       2            7
```

df2:

```
   weekly  accumulated
0       3            0
1       2            2
2       5            7
3       3           10
```

df3:

```
   weekly  accumulated
0       4            0
1       3            3
2       6            9
3       4           13
```

## To solve for 1 dataframe

You need to use cumsum and then subtract the value from first row. That will give you the desired result. here's how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'weekly':[2,1,4,2]})
print (df)
df['accumulated'] = df['weekly'].cumsum() - df.iloc[0,0]
print (df)
```

Original dataframe:

```
   weekly
0       2
1       1
2       4
3       2
```

Updated dataframe:

```
   weekly  accumulated
0       2            0
1       1            1
2       4            5
3       2            7
```